# Oracle Source endpoint test connection fails in AWS DMS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, rds, dms

I configured source and target endpoint for DMS services, The migration I need to perform is from EC2 to Oracle RDS using AWS DMS and both are 12c.

I am testing the source end point and I am getting this error

> Endpoint identifier
>   Replication instance
>   Status
>   Failure message
>   ec2-172-31-6-111
>   test-dms-oracle
>   failed
>   Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1022307, errMessage=ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor OCI error., errDetails=]

I don't feel this occurs because of Network error since, I tried testing the connection with all ports open. And I can able to access the DB within EC2
please refer the screenshot

[image]

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORA-12514 could mean either of
a. The SERVICE_NAME in the TNSNAMES.ORA or Connect-String does not match the Database Service Name
b.  The Listener is running on a non-default port and the database instance does not have LOCAL_LISTENER configured to the listener (thus the instance does not update the listener with its service name)

Run LSNRCTL STATUS and LSNRCTL SERVICES on the database server to verify the running services.

Hemant K Chitale

Comment: Thank you Mr. Hemant, I made the tnsping and found that the Service name I entered doesn't match with the Source Endpoint. I successfully imported the schema from EC2 to RDS using DMS.

Comment: Please provide the steps for this if you can.